# How to set System.Security transparency on project level

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to set/adjust the Assembly Security levels (Transparent, critical, etc...) on a project?
According to [this MS article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/security-transparent-code-level-2) we can define them by adding a line like this to the top of the namespace:

```
using System.SomeOtherNameSpace;

[assembly: System.Security.SecurityTransparent]
namespace MyProject.MyTransparentNameSpace
{
   //whole bunch of classes and enums
}
```

But is there a setting somewhere that I can add this attribute to my project rather than defining this in the code?

---

**A little bit background**:

I have a MS.Net FrameWork 4.7.2 project (let's call it Project *High-Level*) that references a .Net Standard 2.0 project (let's call it project *low-level*) and in project *low-level*, there are some public namespaces, classes and enums that are used throughout *High-Level*project.

I was getting `MethodAccessException` on a line in the *High-Level* project that references an enum from *low-level* (.NetStandard) project. All my methods, classes and interfaces were public, even looking at the values through Watches worked fine, however, I kept getting [`Method HighLevel.XXX cannot access method LowLevel.get_enum()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987421/system-typeaccessexception-attempt-by-method-x-to-access-type-y-failed) exception. I tried many things and at the end of the day, using that `[assembly: ....]` got rid of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> we can define them by adding a line like this to the top of the namespace

That attribute is on the *assembly* (the project).  The attribute is prefixed with `assembly:`, not `namespace:`.  It's position there is coincidental and can be moved elsewhere (as long as it is outside of a namespace).  You can move it into the project's AssemblyInfo.cs file, next to the project's `AssemblyVersion` attribute.  It should be (but doesn't have to be) located inside your projects Properties folder.

See: [What is AssemblyInfo.cs used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13180543/what-is-assemblyinfo-cs-used-for)